# Ideas on building an online slideshow/presentation that tracks and makes sure visitor is actually going through the whole thing

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am trying to build an online teach tool that shows a presentation/slideshow.  It needs to have the ability to track and make sure users are staying through the whole process.

The client used this example to show me what they were looking for visually:

https://www.enrolldi.com/demo/express/

Now, I let them know that with a flash video, there would really be no way to do any sort of tracking.

What I envision is creating a multi page slideshow which has you click next for the next page.  This "next" button would use some sort of javascript to enable the next button after a specified amount of time.  A person would be logged in during this, so every-time the person moves on to next slide, I would track their process in the database.

**My question is, is there any better ways to do this tracking.

Also, doing simple animations like cursor movements etc, can really only be accomplished well by using flash I assume?  They mentioned using voice over etc.**

Comment: How serious are you about making sure users don't circumvent your tracking?

Comment: decently serious. i cant think of ways to do a better job then what i have in mind tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the server is where your focus should be I think. I'd deliever an anti-forgery token to the user that the client script had to hold to advance to the next segment, then check the timestamp on the server each time.

This doesn't have to be done using clicks on delayed buttons either, you could and probably hide the whole thing so that the user is unaware and only post a warning when the user starts advancing too quickly. Otherwise they'll be watching for the button to appear and be distracted. If you go this route make sure you can flash your warning at regular intervals. If you wait, say until the end of a 30 minute module to tell your user that they need to spend at least 20 minutes on it and they just skimmed it in 10, they are not gonna go back and re-read it, they'll just sit there and wait. AJAX would probably be a good idea for a site like this, so you can keep a good handle on what is happening on the user's computer, and it will make the whole system much harder to circumvent.

You should probably penalize users for trying to advance *very* quickly as well, if they click next in the first few seconds of visiting a slide for the first time, pop up a full screen 'extra serious' warning explaining that they need to read the slide or something and don't let them close that one for 30 seconds or whatever, maybe longer for repeat offenders.